# Symfony2 filtering results - problems with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am basic user of **symfony2**.I am trying to perform filtering search result functionality using jquery in **Symfony2:**

**1.** In twig view in javascript section  I get data from input and send ajax request to controller usung `$.ajax()`

**2.** In controller I get data from database.Last instruction I make  `return new jsonRespons(data)`

**3.** In the last step I present data in success function of ajax method. Evrything works perfectly except image display. In database I store image names. I try to dysplay it using **code below:**

```
     var zmienna='images/ksiazki/'+data[i]['source']+'.jpg' 
     <div class="book-image"><img src="{{asset(zmienna)}}" class="img-responsive"/></div>
```

It does not work. Please help. Maybe my approach to this task is wrong?How should I do it in Symfony2 correctly? Is it possible to send ajax result' data not to javascript section but to main section of twig template?

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display JavaScript variable on Server Side (twig) so it will never work.

If you want to display this then after ajax call is performed you need to create img element and add it to book-image div

With jquery you can do as following. Add success function to ajax call

```
success: function (response) {
    for(var el in response) {
       var el = '<img src=" + ' el.src ' +" class="img-responsive"/>'
       $(".book-image").append(el);
    }
}
```

this is assuming that in your JSON there is array of elements with src attribute. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        src: "path/to/image/image.jpg"
    },
    {
        src: "path/to/image/otherimage.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for response. You' re right, but problem for me is that in twig templates I must use {{asset ()}} function to display images which not work in javascript. I can not use 'normal' path e.g <img src="folder/images/image.jpg"/>. However maybe I can use it?

Comment: {{ asset() }} will return full path to the image before javascript is executed so maybe you don't need javascript and just use `<img src="images/ksiazki/{{ asset(zmienna) }}">` and after it is returned then do something with them in JavaScript if needed